# How to detect a crack in an image?

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, deep-learning, object-detection

How to detect such cracks that you can see in the attached images? I have tried some OpenCV algorithms like blob detection (cv::SimpleBlobDetector) but couldn't get any results.

It is a cropped image, the full image has some other features as well, so I am not sure thresholding can work because I have to get the bounding box of the detected crack. One way is to assign several (region of interest) ROI and try to detect within that ROI, but this crack doesn't appear at the same location in the image. Any idea?

Can this problem be solved with machine/deep learning (like object detection)? If I train a model with a crack dataset? Because the crack part of the image doesn't have lots of features so I am not sure this method will work. Please guide.

Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use  mathematical morphology operation.
By example Matlab code:

```
a=imread('in.png');
se=strel( 'disk', 7);
b = imgaussfilt(a,1.3);
c=b-imopen(b,se);
c=3*c;
d=imclearborder(c);
imwrite(d, 'out.png');
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks alex, this solution works but not for every case. Some low signal-to-noise ratio images do not give any result as the cracks are very small and low in contrast. Yves method works best for most of the cases.

Answer (score 1):

These cracks are difficult to detect because the image is noisy (presumably X-ray) and the contrast poor, so the signal-to-noise ratio is low.

I would try by applying a gaussian filter for denoising, but only in the horizontal direction, to preserve the horizontal edges. Then detection of the horizontal edges.

This is about what a Gabor filter does. You can try different orientations.

Comment: Amazing thanks. How didn't I know about the Gabor filter. I got reasonable detection results. But I believe some more processing would be needed to get 100% results. The signal-to-noise ratio is very low for some images. Now, the problem arises with Gabor, I get curved part as well. If the angle of crack and curve/edge matches. How to discard those? and If a crack is vertical, I get straight vertical edges as well.

Comment: @maxpayne: I don't get your point "If a crack is vertical, I get straight vertical edges as well." This is the expected result, isn't it ?